# Is there an obvious way to see the changelog of a maven plugin?

Tags: maven, plugins, changelog

In particular I was searching for changes in recent versions of the maven install plugin.

Looks like a stupid question for me, but I did struggle for some time to find the [apache blog entry](https://blogs.apache.org/maven/entry/apache-maven-install-plugin-version), finally succeeding with Google search *changelog "apache maven plugin"*.

Comment: What exactly are you searching for?  In the blog post there is a link to the release notes also it contains a full list of changes with their appropriate jira tickets... ?

Comment: The blog post is just fine. Trouble was to find the blog post and I was wondering whether there is a way to find it directly or a maven plugin I overlooked to list the changes.

Comment: There is also an annoucement mailing https://www.mail-archive.com/announce@maven.apache.org/ which contains all release announcement. Hm.. on the other hands it seemed not that obvious where to find... seemed to be there is space for improvement.

Comment: Thanks. This will at least help me with other plugins as well.